# 'foundation-apps' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

I did

> npm install -g foundation-cli bower gulp

got

```
       /|
      | |  /| .
 .  /\|  \/ |/|
 |\/          |         Thanks for installing Foundation for Apps
 ||\__/\____/||         ------------------------------------------
```

Then, I did

> gem install bundler

and got

> Successfully installed bundler-1.10.5

but when I tried

> foundation-apps new myApp

I got

> 'foundation-apps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

working on windows 7, behind proxy

Answer (score 3):

I have it working in Windows 10 but I believe it is the same.
When I check the npm folder: `C:\Users\(YourName)\AppData\Roaming\npm`
The command name is **foundation** instead of **foundation-apps**
So you should type: `foundation new`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fedora-22 and potentially other OSes Siu Pang Tommy Choi's answer is also applicable; that is, replace foundation-apps new NAME with the foundation new NAME.

This is the first time I've encountered this problem, so perhaps there has been a change within the last few versions that has deprecated the foundation-apps command (or else you should consider this a work-around).  Just make sure that you correctly specify that you want an 'app' and not a 'site' when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

foundation studios install instructions on the url https://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/installation

tells this

"You now have access to the foundation-apps command on your system! You'll use this to set up and update new projects"

Siu Pang Tommy Choi gave the best answer because foundation command worked instead of foundation-apps

still confusing because i am following instructions from the above url.

Are you sure there is no foundation-apps command?